# How to enable JMX monitoring for akka-camel endpoints

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka

I have an Akka application (akka 2.2.0, akka-camel, camel 2.10.5).
The application includes Producer components, i.e.:

```
class MyProducer extends Actor with Producer with akka.actor.ActorLogging {
...
```

I would like to have Camel automatically expose monitoring properties for these producers over JMX, to see how many messages have been exchanged, average times, throughput etc.

In theory [Apache Camel has extensive support for JMX to allow you to monitor and control the Camel managed objects with a JMX client](http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html). In practice, I have enabled the JMX agent

```
    <jmxAgent
            id="agent"
            disabled="false"
            createConnector="true"
            usePlatformMBeanServer="true"
            mbeanServerDefaultDomain="localhost"
            registryPort="1346"
            registerAlways="true"
            registerNewRoutes="true"
            />
```

which causes a series of Camel information to show up as mbeans (as seen, for example, from VisualVM) **but** with no information about my Producer actors under "endpoints".

I have tried decorating the actor with

```
@ManagedResource
```

This doesn't appear to have any effect.
The documentation says

> "In Camel 2.1 onwards only singleton endpoints are registered as the
>   overhead for non singleton will be substantial in cases where
>   thousands or millions of endpoints are used. This can happens when
>   using a Recipient List EIP or from a ProducerTemplate that sends a lot
>   of messages. "

I wonder if my Producer actors do not expose information because of this (it is unclear to me what, exactly, is the type of endpoints resulting from the Producer trait).

**What exactly do I need to do to enable JMX monitoring for my akka-camel endpoints (as resulting from using the Producer trait)?**

**EDIT:**
Viktor pointed out that I needed to redefine a configuration attribute.
This is necessary but not sufficient. It is also required to force Camel to manage your endpoints. I had to add this:

```
camelContext.addRegisterEndpointCallback(new EndpointStrategy {
  def registerEndpoint(name: String, ep: Endpoint) = {
    camelContext.getManagementStrategy.manageObject(ep)
    ep
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Akka Documentation is quite extensive.

```
akka {
  camel {
  # Whether JMX should be enabled or disabled for the Camel Context
  jmx = off
  …
  }
}
```

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/general/configuration.html#akka-camel

Answer (score 1):

I would start with looking at the latest Akka Camel Docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/camel.html).  If you scroll down a bit, you will see a heading called `CamelExtension`.  Under this heading, you will see info on how to get the `CamelContext` used by the system.  Once you have the `CamelContext`, you will notice there is a method on it called `setManagementStrategy`.  You should be able to use this to set an instance of `ManagedManagementStrategy` (doc [here](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/management/ManagedManagementStrategy.html)) and hopefully that will enable the JMX goodness you need.  I say hopefully because I don't know for sure as I have not tried this myself.

Comment: Your comment has also helped me. Will edit in the question to reflect the final solution. Thanks!